# Upload images to server ImageSwitcher

Tags: android

I am a beginner in writing applications for Android.

I need an "ImageSwitcher" and populate it with images from a server queue. I've already researched a lot on the internet before coming to ask. Would anyone post some code samples or give some hint on what to search for?

Comment: From the official close reasons: questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 0):

What you're going to want to do it Create a view like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
 android:orientation="vertical"  
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">  

  <Gallery  
       android:id="@+id/gallery"  
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />  

  <ImageSwitcher  
       android:id="@+id/image_switcher"  
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" />  
</LinearLayout>
```

And then, behind the scenes in some sort of AsyncTask, download the images, and then display them.  That code isn't too difficult.

This [project](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) on github may be of use as well. It seems to be good for lazy loading images in a listview, but I bet it could easily be modified to load a gallery.

Comment: Precisava exatamente dessa parte de baixar as imagens e popular a galeria ja tentei de tudo e não funciona :/

Comment: Then you're not trying the correct things. I have a similar thing that downloads an populates an a listview in a asynctask but it is in an app that I sell, so I'm not distributing it.

Comment: Good morning, Daniel
Not only can post the code that downloads images from the web service?
Already tried everything on the internet and not found anything, the problem is q never needed to do this so do not even know where to start.
thank you